# Powershell Exchange Delete old Phone Sync Devices

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a Powershell Script that will clean up any Phones that haven't synced in at least 110 days with the Exchange 2013 Server.

My code will pull the data and export it to CSV but when I try to pipe in the Remove-MobileDevice command to delete the devices the script fails to do so. Nothing I found on the Internet has been of much help so far. Most are using the outdated ActiveSyncDevice cmdlets.

Here's my code, I'm new to PowerShell and appreciate any help:

```
Get-MobileDevice -result unlimited | Get-MobileDeviceStatistics | where {$_.LastSuccessSync -le (Get-Date).AddDays(“-110”)} | select devicetype, deviceidentity, deviceos, deviceuseragent, identity | Export-csv C:\PhoneSync\Logs\Stale_Devices_110days_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss')).csv | foreach (Remove-MobileDevice -Identity DeviceUserAgent -confirm:$false)
```

Comment: One issue is that you are attempting pipe to your final `foreach` after exporting your csv. Probably worth while to break your one-liner into an a multiple line script for clarity.

Comment: Did you inspect the CSV file?

Comment: I tried removing the export and it still bombs out with this error:



`The mobile device DeviceUserAgent cannot be found.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-MobileDevice], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=WEBMAIL,RequestId=771c3306-817b-4049-a076-e398d73fbaed,TimeStamp=1/18/2017 6:59:23 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet
   -ManagementObjectNotFoundException] DFB3D711,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Tasks.RemoveMobileDevice
    + PSComputerName        : webmail.server.com`

Comment: Yes, the CSV contains the device I want deleted.

Comment: That issue is because foreach object you are passing you are statically defining the Identity as "DeviceUserAgent" with this: `-Identity DeviceUserAgent` Try changing it to `-Identity $_.DeviceUserAgent`.

Answer (score 0):

Can I provide a better (automatically) solution which is build into Exchange? Since Exchange 2013/2016 Microsoft added the EasMaxInactivityForDeviceCleanup value to the throttling policy and described it [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351045(v=exchg.160).aspx) as:

> The EasMaxInactivityForDeviceCleanup parameter specifies the length of
>   time that a user's device partnerships will remain active. By default,
>   there is no limit to the number of days that a user's device
>   partnerships will remain active. Use this value if you want to
>   minimize the amount of inactive device partnerships in your
>   organization. To use this setting, specify a value in days since the
>   user's last sync time to cause the device partnership to be removed.

So if I would be you, I would create a new throttling policy as explained [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/315-build-an-ms-exchange-throttling-policy-to-remove-inactive-mobile-device-partnerships.html) and assign that to your users. After that is in place and if a user is adding a new device, the Exchange server will check the configured devices and will automatically delete the unused one, during the adding from the new device. Then you do not need to run a script, the server will mostly take care of them automatically.

Comment: Thank you for that solution, which will be great going forward, but what about the devices there now? I'd like to get this script working to purge them.
EDIT: It says this cmdlet is only available on Ex2016, we are using 2013.

Comment: I personally would wait as you said you are a new to powershell. I personally wouldn´t risk to delete any administration/monitoring devices if you haven´t the needed skills yet. The point is, how often did the user get new "toys" to play with? I would wait here. But if you really need a script you can check the one in the URL above (or [here is it again](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/315-build-an-ms-exchange-throttling-policy-to-remove-inactive-mobile-device-partnerships.html)).

Comment: Its policy from management. Its currently done manually by hand by logging into each user's mailbox. I'm just trying to automate the process.

The problem with the script in your URL is when I try to add exporting the results to CSV it fails.

Comment: lol someone who doesn't know scripting. I use VBScript a lot more and am just getting into PowerShell so still getting a hang for the syntax and what not. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your list of devices, including the Guid, You can run this to delete all the devices in that .csv file.

Import-CSV (your_path_and_file_name.csv) | foreach{Remove-MobileDevice -Identity $_.Guid}